# Появление круглого блока

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Хочу реализовать следующее: при нажатии на кнопку во все стороны разъезжается круглый блок. вот [пример](https://www.ljosleidarinn.is/) на буржуйском сайте (смотрите кнопки meira и adstod).

Как я понимаю: есть у меня кнопка, есть большой div со скругленными углами изначально скрытый (display: none ?). А как быть дальше - не знаю. буду рад любым наводкам и помощи. заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('button_active');
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.button_active {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(-25%, -25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button" id="button"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var growth = false;
var get = function(obj) {
  return document.getElementById(obj)
};
get('two').onclick = function() {
  if (growth) {
    get('one').style.width = '50px';
    get('one').style.height = '50px';
    get('one').style.left = '0px';
    get('one').style.top = '0px';
    growth = false
  } else {
    get('one').style.width = '500px';
    get('one').style.height = '500px';
    get('one').style.left = '-250px';
    get('one').style.top = '-250px';
    growth = true
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
}
#two {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id='one'></div>
  <div id='two'></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```